# How to resolve issue of Error decoding incoming SAML message?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, spring-saml

I am getting error `Error decoding incoming SAML message` for SAML request.

I have configured the ADFS 2.0 , windows server 2008 , SAML 2.0. and SSO is working well using SAML 2.0

Now my client need windows server 2012 and they have configured it and restored old servers config. in to new server but SAML authentication giving me the below errors.

```
Error in SAML : Error decoding incoming SAML message
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error decoding incoming SAML message
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.MessageDecodingException: Could not decode artifact response message.
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.java:123)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.HTTPArtifactDecoderImpl.doDecode(HTTPArtifactDecoderImpl.java:94)
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:79)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:77)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.MessageDecodingException: Error when sending request to artifact resolution service.
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.getArtifactResponse(ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.java:98)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:104)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:109)
    at org.opensaml.ws.transport.http.httpclient.OutputStreamRequestEntity.writeRequest(OutputStreamRequestEntity.java:46)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.getArtifactResponse(ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.java:96)
    ... 51 more
```

The issue is at the side of adfs server configuration but I didn't get the solution. 
Give any suggestion regarding ADFS 2.0 configuration or etc is best help for me.

It give me the error like `Error when sending request to artifact resolution service.` but I don't know how to start artifact resolution service?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it does not appear to be about programming.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I think you have to check the solution of Vladimír Schäfer. He had try to give answer at coding side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Changed default binding to POST in SP metadata and saved the file as my_sp.xml under this folder
   "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\SunflowerSET\WEB-INF\classes\resources\security" on server
2. Downloaded metadata from new ADFS server (ADFS101) and stored that as  FederationMetadata.xml under this folder  C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\SunflowerSET\WEB-INF\classes\resources\security  on server.
3. Deleted relying party trust rule from ADFS
4. Configured new relying party trust  rule on ADFS101 using the new my_sp.xml metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Spring SAML seems to have trouble connecting to the endpoint specified in the ADFS's IDP metadata which you have imported. You can see the endpoint URL in the metadata in element `ArtifactResolutionService`. Make sure it is possible to connect to this URL from the Spring SAML instance.

As another option, you can use different binding which doesn't require direct backend connectivity to ADFS. You can instruct IDP to use `HTTP-POST` when sending message back to SP by removing the Artifact assertion consumer service from your SP metadata and uploading the new version to IDP.

It is also possible to control which binding should be used by IDP when sending responses to SP using `WebSSOProfileOptions` and property `assertionConsumerIndex`, as you can see in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-sso-process-sp-init), chapter 9.2.1.

Comment: If I use the urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST binding then Do I need artifact resolution service?

Comment: No, you don't. Please note that I made a mistake in the original answer above, the correct property to control binding used by IDP to send messages to SP is assertionConsumerIndex.

Comment: Are you talking about this config?<property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>